# Migration of old, unanswered question to newer SE site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have a [question I asked over a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246161/jenkins-pipeline-job-cant-find-script-due-to-tmp-path-being-created) here on Stack Exchange. I've yet to be offered a workable solution and the problem's gotten in my way again.

The DevOps stack exchange would be a much better place for the question as there's a higher percentage of people versed in the particular thing I'm asking about, but DevOps didn't exist back when I asked the question.

Is there a way to migrate the question to DevOps? Alternatively, should it be closed here and asked again over there? I could write it much better now, with a more succinct example, but I know the stack frowns on crossposting.

Comment: Yup - move it.  Delete it here and repost to the more appropriate site.

Comment: So here's the deal.  The accepted answer is essentially what I'd be regurgitating here, so I felt it better to close as a dupe since that effectively describes the scenario.  Only employees could migrate a question like this.  I *personally* don't see a reason for it *to* be migrated since it has been well-received here and it's still on-topic for Stack Overflow (since developers *do* use this tool called Jenkins for CI builds sometimes).

Comment: @Makoto Understood, good to know that's how it works. In answer to your second part; I suppose I'm hoping putting the question in front of a more targeted audience might have better odds of coming up with a workable answer. Would it be unreasonable of me to post a new question on DevOps, or is that considered cross-posting?

Comment: I would argue that it's a cross-post.  I'm sure there's existing literature here on MSO that describes this case, though.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry I don't think I'm grasping your meaning; does that mean there might be a case for me to go ahead and ask, or...?

Comment: *Don't* ask, since I feel like it'd be a cross-post, but I would encourage you to look around here to see if there's existing opinions on this already.

Comment: @Makoto Gotcha, thank you for clarifying!